# jQuery function - pass params from the URL into the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following function:

It bassicly takes the value form clicked `href` and than load file into the `#loader div` with the same name.

```
$('.loader').click( function() {


            // Check clicked element href
            var ActiveTab = $(this).attr("href");

            //Content
            var TrimedClickedTab = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);
            $('#loaderDiv').load( TrimedClickedTab +'.html', function() {
                    // Show New Loaded Div
            }); 
            return false;
    });
```

**How can I pass param into the function form the URL and than run it with this param?

I want the URL to set the `var ActiveTab = "#form"`**

I'm looking to run this on the load, so it would load straight away given file. ( `var #ActiveTab`)

Comment: you can use activetab variable inside callback function.No issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
var path = document.location.toString();
var anchor = '#' + path.split('#')[1];
```

So, if your URL looks like "http://example.org/test#form", anchor will contain "#form"

Comment: Yes, that is the first bit, but how now pass this `var Activetab = #form` into my function to run?

Comment: You could access #form directly in window.location.hash :)